# Match a string using regular expressions?

Tags: java, regex, string

I am working with JSP and Servlet and user is going to input some string from that form in the JSP page.

And that string can be like this -

```
/pp/dc/dc1/h1
...
/pp/dc/dc1/h100

or

/pp/dc/dc2/h1
...
/pp/dc/dc2/h100

or

/pp/dc/dc3/h1
...
/pp/dc/dc3/h100
```

Here `pp` and `dc` are not going to change at all. Sometimes, they can pass `dc1` or `dc2` or `dc3` and they will always pass a string like this which starts with `h` and then followed by some number like `h1` or `h2` or `h100`.

so that means sometimes string can be like this -

```
/pp/dc/dc1/h10

or

/pp/dc/dc3/h3

or

/pp/dc/dc2/h10
```

So my question is how do I check for these kind of patterns using regular expressions. If there is any string after `h10` or any number followed by `h` like this -

```
/pp/dc/dc2/h10/pro
```

then I will return false otherwise returns true if it is in the same pattern as shown above.

Is this possible to do using RegularExpressions?

```
String data = "/pp/dc/dc3/h1"
```

Comment: It's possible. Have you tried? If not you can toy around with www.regex101.com. It's very helpful and you seem like you know exactly what you want just not how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
^/pp/dc/dc[123]/h[0-9]+$
```

Working regex example:

http://regex101.com/r/mJ8hI7

Comment: Thanks MElliott for the help. In my case, instead `dc1`, `dc2` and `dc3` are three different strings, they are not dc followed by integer. It was just an example but I guess there was some confusion in that. In my case, I have `dcp` as one string instead of `dc1`, `dcs` as second string instead of `dc2` and `dcl` as third string instead of `dc3`. So is there any way to have these three string in the regular expression?

Comment: @user2809564, Yes, sure, but first, is it Always `p`, `s`, or `l` exclusively? or just any letter? Or possibly any alpha-numeric character?

Comment: I got that working after reading some tutorial.s Thanks for the help.

Comment: @user2809564 - Excellent!!  :)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that with this regex:

```
^\/pp\/dc\/dc[123]\/h([1-9]{1,2}|100)$
```

And you could verify if this is what you want in [http://www.regexper.com/#%5E%5C%2Fpp%5C%2Fdc%5C%2Fdc%5B123%5D%5C%2Fh(%5B1-9%5D%7B1%2C2%7D%7C100)%24](http://www.regexper.com/#%5E%5C%2Fpp%5C%2Fdc%5C%2Fdc%5B123%5D%5C%2Fh%28%5B1-9%5D%7B1%2C2%7D%7C100%29%24)

EDIT: I add an example in regex101 here http://regex101.com/r/eI2yO9
Note that this regex doesn't allow the last number to be greater than 100 as you specified. Also note that in this example the / are not escaped, but I think you have to use them depending the language.

EDIT: If you want to match the string as you say in your comment, you can achieve that with

```
^\/pp\/dc\/dc[psl]\/h([1-9]{1,2}|100)$
```

You can see in http://regex101.com/r/iW1vL3 or in [http://www.regexper.com/#%5E%5C%2Fpp%5C%2Fdc%5C%2Fdc%5Bpsl%5D%5C%2Fh(%5B1-9%5D%7B1%2C2%7D%7C100)%24](http://www.regexper.com/#%5E%5C%2Fpp%5C%2Fdc%5C%2Fdc%5Bpsl%5D%5C%2Fh%28%5B1-9%5D%7B1%2C2%7D%7C100%29%24)

Comment: Thanks Airam for the help. In my case, instead `dc1`, `dc2` and `dc3` are three different strings, they are not dc followed by integer. It was just an example but I guess there was some confusion in that. In my case, I have `dcp` as one string instead of `dc1`, `dcs` as second string instead of `dc2` and `dcl` as third string instead of `dc3`. So is there any way to have these three string in the regular expression?

Comment: @user2809564 I've edited my answer to accomplish what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If regex is not a strict requirement, I guess you can do something based on string.split("/") method. You can then appropriately check each of the token as per your requirements in a simple loop.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really easy to "count" with regex, but it is doable:

```
^       (?# match start of string)
/pp     (?# match /pp literally)
/dc     (?# match /dc literally)
/dc     (?# match /dc literally)
[1-3]   (?# match a number 1-3)
/h      (?# match /h literally)
(?:     (?# start non-capturing group)
  [1-9] (?# match a number 1-9)
 |      (?# OR)
  [1-9] (?# match a number 1-9)
  [0-9] (?# match a number 0-9)
 |      (?# OR)
  100   (?# match 100 literally)
)       (?# end non-capturing group)
$       (?# match end of string)
```

[Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/uC7gO8)

This will match `/h1` - `/h3`, and `/d1` - `/d100`.